# How does TileStache handle cache invalidation?

Tags: openstreetmap, cache, tilestache

We are trying to set up our own openstreetmap server. From what I [read here](http://tilestache.org/doc/#caches), you can use a variety of caches to speed up serving the data.

Now, once a week, the people of openstreetmap provides a differential update with the changes in the maps.

If I import those changes once a week, how does TileStache know that what it has generated is no longer valid? Does it handle it itself, or should I invalidate the cache from somewhere else?

Can I do it intelligently? ie, only invalidate the regions that contain changes.

Comment: This is assuming the cache I choose doesn't handle a TTL natively

Comment: For what I know, such function is not built inside TileStache and you have to manage it yourself to delete cache when data are updated.